# Use AWS Kinesis as a data source for an EMR MapReduce job

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, emr, amazon-kinesis

I set up a AWS Kinesis stream that receive data from multiple sources. I'd like to process that data in multiple incremental batches using MapReduce in EMR.

How do I specify the input source in my job? Are there any specific libraries to handle a Kinesis record? Sample code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To specify Kinesis as the input to EMR, Amazon provides a JAR extension for Hive and Pig which handles the iteration and check-pointing.

For Hive, sample code can be found in the "Run the Ad-hoc Hive query" part of [this tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/query-kinesis.html). A similar tutorial exists [for Pig](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/kinesis-pig.html).